# Hyperic Java APIs

Tags: java, hyperic

I have written some Java code through which I fetch metrics from Hyperic Server for some operations.  I have not been able to fetch the value of these metrics.

for eq I have metric CPU Idle but when i use `List<Data Point> dp= m1.getDataPoint()` where `m1` is the metric data object of metric CPU Idle. In the output the size of list `dp` is `0`.

I'm having this problem with all metrics except "availability". What should I do?

I have also checked the time interval in the graphical interface; it is showing the corresponding values.

the code is

```
 //  m_rrc is resource ( Process Server) on agent
for (int z = 0; z < m_rrrc.size(); z++) {
    System.out.println(m_rrrc.get(z).getName())
    MetricsResponse m_mr= m_a.getMetrics(m_rrrc.get(z));

    // m_m is metric like CPU idle CPU utilization, System CPU
    List<Metric> m_m = m_mr.getMetric();

    for (int a = 0; a < m_m.size(); a++) {
        MetricDataResponse m_mdr = m_mdapi.getData(m_m.get(a), 1309147200,1309147800);
        MetricData m_md = m_mdr.getMetricData();

        System.out.println(m_md.getMetricName());

        List<DataPoint> m_dp = m_md.getDataPoint();
        System.out.println(m_dp.size());

        for (int b = 0; b < m_dp.size(); b++) {
            System.out.println("abc");
            System.out.println(m_dp.get(b).getValue());
            System.out.println("i am Prannoy Mittal");
        }
    }
}
```

here size of data point list in  output for all metrics is zero

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will have to post some of your code showing what you are doing.

Comment: now can u help in it..??

Comment: I'ved fixed it for you here already, but if you make sure the code you post if formatted nicely to begin with people are more likely to read through it and help you.

Comment: Adding to what bemace said, with clear, legible code, not only will others be more likely to help, it will be easier for _you_ to help yourself. It's difficult to see problems in disorganized text.

Comment: thaxs..dats kk...but any1 help me in telling why list of  data points is  empty

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample source code from Hyperic (http://svn.hyperic.org/projects/hqapi/trunk/src/org/hyperic/hq/hqapi1/test/MetricData_test.java), if you can put right 'assertEquals' in your code I am sure you will see where the problem is. Good luck

```
    public void testGetEnabledMetricData() throws Exception {

    MetricApi api = getApi().getMetricApi();
    Resource r = getLocalPlatformResource(false, false);
    MetricsResponse resp = api.getEnabledMetrics(r);
    hqAssertSuccess(resp);

    assertTrue("No enabled metrics found for " + r.getName(),
               resp.getMetric().size() > 0);
    Metric m = resp.getMetric().get(0);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long start = end - (8 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    MetricDataResponse dataResponse = api.getMetricData(m.getId(),
                                                           start, end);
    hqAssertSuccess(dataResponse);
    assertTrue("No metric data found for " + m.getName(),
               dataResponse.getMetricData().getDataPoint().size() > 0);
    for (DataPoint d : dataResponse.getMetricData().getDataPoint()) {

        assertTrue("Metric point timestamp greater than end time. ts=" +
                   d.getTimestamp() + " end=" + end,
                   d.getTimestamp() <= end);
        assertTrue("Metric point timestamp less than start time ts=" +
                   d.getTimestamp() + " start=" + start,
                   d.getTimestamp() >= start);
        assertTrue("Metric value less than zero",
                   d.getValue() >= 0);
    }
}
```